# Integration in octave - No default value for argument 1 error

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-integration

I am trying to use the `quad` integration function using anonymous functions in Octave. The bit of code that I'm working with is:

```
   for i = 0:imax
      t = i*dt;
      theta = omega*t - k*xmid*cos(Angw) - k*ymid*sin(Angw);
      eta = amp*cos(theta);
      dz = (eta+h)/(nz-1);
      dS = dz;
      for j = 1:nz
          z = -h + dz * (j-1)
          u = (k*amp*g/omega)*((cosh(k*(h+z)))/cosh(k*h))*sin(theta)*cos(Angw);
          v = (k*amp*g/omega)*((cosh(k*(h+z)))/cosh(k*h))*cos(theta)*sin(Angw);
          w = (k*amp*g/omega)*((sinh(k*(h+z)))/cosh(k*h))*cos(theta);
          udot = k*amp*g*((cosh(k*(h+z)))/cosh(k*h))*cos(theta)*cos(Angw);
          vdot = -k*amp*g*((cosh(k*(h+z)))/cosh(k*h))*sin(theta)*sin(Angw);
          wdot = -k*amp*g*((sinh(k*(h+z)))/cosh(k*h))*sin(theta);
  %         Velocity Vector Components
          Vel = [u, v, w];
          Acc = [udot, vdot, wdot];
          Un = Vel*C;
          Unx = Un(1);
          Uny = Un(2);
          Unz = Un(3);
          Un_mag = sqrt(Unx^2 + Uny^2 + Unz^2);
  %         Force Components
          Fd  =  Cd*0.5*rho*D*Un_mag*Vel;
          Fi =  Cm*rho*(pi*D^2/4.0)*Acc;
          Ftot = @(x) ((Fd + Fi)*C);
          Fx(j) = Ftot(:,1);
          Fy(j) = Ftot(:,2);
          Fz(j) = Ftot(:,3);
      end
  %         Total force along the cylinder
      ftotx = quad(Fx(j),-z,0)
    end
```

The error I am getting is:

`no default value for argument 1`

I am correctly calculating Ftot in the first loop so I'm confused why I can't do it this way? I want to integrate Ftot separately over each component (Fx(j), Fy(j) and Fz(j)). Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Ftot = @(x) (Fd + Fi)*C;` that line makes no sense, you are defining a constant function which does not care about the inputs. Could you give a mathematical definition of the integral you are trying to evaluate?

Comment: Hi, I've included the values I'm using for C. Ftot is the sum of the equations for Fd and Fi multiplied by each component of `C`, which is a 3x3 matrix. This means Ftot is an array of 3 components, which are equivalent to Fx, Fy, and Fz. Hopefully this is a bit clearer!

Comment: `Ftot` is a function handle which has one input argument (`x`), it's not an array.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to implement. Could you give the formula you are trying to implement or explain it?

Comment: I am trying to integrate the equation given by Ftot, which is simply a combination of Fd and Fi (I only broke it up like that as it's quite a long equation so it's to be clearer).

Comment: Ok I've added the code that I left off the original question, maybe this makes it clearer. I want to integrate Ftot over all values of z (or j as z is set dependent on step j). Does this make more sense?

Comment: Without knowing the forumla for Ftot you are trying to implement, I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Apologies but I don't understand what you're saying? The Formula for Ftot is the formula for Fd and Fi added together and multiplied by C... 
`Fd  =  Cd*0.5*rho*D*Un_mag*Vel;`
          `Fi =  Cm*rho*(pi*D^2/4.0)*Acc;` 
C is just a direction cosine matrix (3x3 matrix so finds three components of Ftot)